# ctypes: Passing string by reference

Tags: python, ctypes

With regard to Python 2.5, I wish to implement the following C code in python:

C code:

```
#include <wtypes.h>

__declspec(dllexport) X_ERROR __stdcall GetAdmSize(INT* piAdmSize, CHAR** chBuf, INT iBufSize);

int iProgSize = 0;
char szProgSize[50];
char* pszProgSize = szProgSize;
error = GetAdmSize(&iProgSize, &pszProgSize, 49);
```

Python code:

```
from ctypes import *
c_bool = c_int

x = windll.LoadLibrary("x.dll")
iProgSize = c_int()
szProgSize = create_string_buffer(50)
getAdmSize = x.AdkGetAdmSize
getAdmSize.argtypes = [POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_char_p), c_int]
status = getAdmSize(byref(iProgSize), byref(szProgSize), 49)
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    status = getAdmSize(byref(iProgSize), (szProgSize), 49)
ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_c_char_p instance instead of c_char_Array_50
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I tried:

```
pointerToStringBuffer = cast(szProgSize, c_char_p)
status = getAdmSize(byref(iProgSize), byref(pointerToStringBuffer), 49)
```

But this gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    status = getAdmSize(byref(iProgSize), byref(pointerToStringBuffer), 49)
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000031
```

As a matter of interest, I get the same error in C if I call this:

```
error = AdkGetAdmSize((int*)0, (char**)49, 0);
```

Seems like my arguments are not aligned correctly perhaps

Any suggestions?

Comment: from my faulty memory: try to cast (`ctypes.cast()`) the array to a pointer first (they are different types). `ctypes` might do less implicit type conversions than C.

Comment: Your C code looks all wrong. Why would `GetAdmSize` be modifying `pszProgSize`?

Comment: I didn't write the C code, its an example for the library i wish to use. It returns a string via szProgSize containing the program version the dll is specific to. Again I didn't write this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A direct translation of your C code would be more like:

```
from ctypes import *
x = windll.LoadLibrary("x.dll")
iProgSize = c_int(0)
szProgSize = create_string_buffer(50)
pszProgSize = c_char_p(addressof(szProgSize))
getAdmSize = x.GetAdmSize
getAdmSize.argtypes = [POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_char_p), c_int]
status = getAdmSize(byref(iProgSize), byref(pszProgSize), 49)
```

Fake DLL I tested with:

```
typedef int X_ERROR;
typedef int INT;
typedef char CHAR;

#include <string.h>

__declspec(dllexport) X_ERROR __stdcall GetAdmSize(INT* piAdmSize, CHAR** chBuf, INT iBufSize)
{
    *piAdmSize = 5;
    strcpy_s(*chBuf,iBufSize,"abcd");
    return 1;
}
```

Results:

```
>>> x.iProgSize
c_long(5)
>>> x.pszProgSize
c_char_p('abcd')
>>> x.szProgSize.value
'abcd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out I think. I also had to specify the return type:

```
getAdmSize.restype = X_ERROR
```